# docker command is showing nothing in centos7

Tags: docker, command

hi i just installed latest version of docker in Virtual machine with Cent OS 7 and yum update finished.
but my docker's command doesn't work,showing nothing,even docker is on the service list.
and what if i type in `service docker status` the active menu displaying `active(running" since ****")`
it was same as such as tried remove and install again.
please check image file what i attached.
thanks

I took screen shot my problem and what i tried

[image]

Comment: You need a non root user with sudo privileges. Once logged as that user, run this in bash: sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)

Comment: Why should that matter? The root user should be able to run `docker version`. It sounds like this host is already running containers and doing something. Can you post more about the configuration of the daemon? The `redis.conf` error doesn't make sense in this context and almost sounds like something is configured incorrectly.

Comment: check your ACL/SELINUX `getenforce` is it `enforcing` ??

Comment: thank you for replying guys, i solved my problem.I did not install main docker, I just installed docker-client,common.which is installing for dependencies. like I execute brood war without startcraft.fool